# how to get collection based on number of duplicate foreign keys?

Tags: postgresql

I have a batch table, and an item table, the relationship is the batch has many items (item has a batch_id foreign key).

How would I make a query that will find the batches which have more than 100 items?

Comment: Do you need all the rows or just the batch ids?  If the latter, that's just a simple group by with a HAVING clause at the end to filter to >= 100 items.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.* FROM
    batch b LEFT JOIN
    item i ON i.batch_id = b.batch_id
GROUP BY b.batch_id HAVING COUNT (i.batch_id) > 100
```

To get the count by `batch_id`

```
SELECT b.batch_id, COUNT(i.batch_id)
FROM
    batch b LEFT JOIN
    item i ON i.batch_id = b.batch_id
GROUP BY b.batch_id HAVING COUNT (i.batch_id) > 100
```